# Querying XML like SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, language-agnostic, frameworks

Is there any framework for querying XML SQL Syntax,  I seriously tire of iterating through node lists.

---

Or is this just wishful thinking (if not idiotic) and certainly not possible since XML isn't a relational database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/default.asp) and XPath... XQuery is more what you are looking for if a SQL structure is desirable.

Comment: Cool, I've been using XPath because it's implemented in PHP's simpleXML, I guess I just missed XQuery.

Comment: Xquery implements XPath, however it is the work of the devil.

Answer (score 2):

.Net Framework provides LINQ to do this or you can use the .Net System.Data namespace to load data from XML files.

You can even create queries that have joins among the tables, etc.

For example, System.Data.DataTable provides a `ReadXml()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could try LINQ to XML, but it's not language agnostic.

Comment: The LINQ part is .net, so you can use any language with a CLR compiler

Answer (score 1):

[XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/) is a functional language that is closest to SQL.  [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) is a notation for locating a node within the document that is used as part of XSLT and XQuery.

XML databases such as [MarkLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/) serve as XQuery engines for XML data, much as relational databases serve as SQL engines for relational data.

Comment: Sql Server and Oracle support XQuery too.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the problem you are solving. If XML file is pretty large, sometimes it's a necessity to use something like SAX parsers to traverse the file node by node, or you will get OutOfMemoryException or will run out even of virtual memory on your computer.

But, if the expected size of XML file is relatively small, you can simply use something like Linq, also see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088442/what-is-the-purpose-advantage-of-using-yield-return-iterators-in-c/2508429#2508429) - here I tried to explain, how to make traversing through nodes much easier with constructions like **yield return**.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue, I've got MSXML6 reading in 300 meg XML files and using upwards of a Gig of RAM.  Fortunately this worked with win2k and I only had a few problems with VMs with extremely small page files.  I think Yield return would work, but unfortunately I'm a Delphi programmer and SOL for all .NET hotness.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 supports [XML DML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx) on it's native `xml` data type.

Answer (score 0):

XQuery is certainly the way forward.  This is what is used by XML databases like [eXist](http://exist-db.org/) and [MarkLogic](http://www.marklogic.com/).

In the Java world there are several solutions for running XQuery on flat files, most notably [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/)

For .NET, there is not so much available.  Microsoft did have an XQuery library, although this was pulled from .NET 2 and has never resurfaced.  [XQSharp](http://www.xqsharp.com/)  is a  native .NET alternative, although currently only a command line version has been released.