# What is the purpose/advantage of using yield return iterators in C#?

Tags: c#, iterator, yield-return

All of the examples I've seen of using `yield return x;` inside a C# method could be done in the same way by just returning the whole list. In those cases, is there any benefit or advantage in using the `yield return` syntax vs. returning the list?

Also, in what types of scenarios would `yield return` be used that you couldn't just return the complete list?

Comment: Why are you assuming that there is "a list" in the first place? What if there isn't?

Comment: @Eric, I guess that's what I was asking. When would you not have a list in the first place. File streams and infinite sequences are 2 great examples in the answers so far.

Comment: If you have the list then, sure, just return it; but if you're building a list inside of the method and returning that then you could / should be using iterators instead. Yield the items one at a time. There are many benefits.

Comment: *"in what types of scenarios would yield return be used that you wouldn't just return the complete list?"* - How about LINQ...

Comment: I've certainly learned a lot since asking this question 5 years ago!

Comment: The biggest advantage of having `yield`s is you dont have to name yet another intermediate variable.

Comment: I like intermediate variables. They usually greatly simplify readability and debugging.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

But what if you were building a collection yourself?

In general, iterators can be used to **lazily generate a sequence of objects**. For example `Enumerable.Range` method does not have any kind of collection internally. It just generates the next number **on demand**. There are many uses to this lazy sequence generation using a state machine. Most of them are covered under **functional programming concepts**.

In my opinion, if you are looking at iterators just as a way to enumerate through a collection (it's just one of the simplest use cases), you're going the wrong way. As I said, iterators are means for returning sequences. The sequence might even be **infinite**. There would be no way to return a list with infinite length and use the first 100 items. It **has** to be lazy sometimes. **Returning a collection is considerably different from returning a collection generator** (which is what an iterator is). It's comparing apples to oranges.

Hypothetical example:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetPrimeNumbers() {
   for (int num = 2; ; ++num) 
       if (IsPrime(num))
           yield return num;
}

static void Main() { 
   foreach (var i in GetPrimeNumbers()) 
       if (i < 10000)
           Console.WriteLine(i);
       else
           break;
}
```

This example prints prime numbers less than 10000. You can easily change it to print numbers less than a million without touching the prime number generation algorithm at all. In this example, you can't return a list of all prime numbers because the sequence is infinite and the consumer doesn't even know how many items it wants from the start.

Comment: Right. I've built the list, but what dif does it make to return one item at a time vs. returning the whole list?

Comment: Among other reasons, it makes your code more modular so you can load an item, process, then repeat. Also, consider the case where loading an item is very expensive, or there are lots of them (millions say). In those cases, loading the entire list is undesirable.

Comment: @Dennis: For a linearly stored list in memory, it might not have a difference but if you were, for instance, enumerating a 10GB file and processing each line one by one, it would make a difference.

Comment: +1 for an excellent answer - I would also add that the yield keyword allows iterator semantics to be applied to sources that are not traditionally considered collections - such as network sockets, web services, or even concurrency problems (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481714/ccr-yield-and-vb-net)

Comment: Nice example, so basically it's a collection generator that is based on the context (e.g. method call)and doesn't kick in to action until something tries to access it, whereas a traditional collection method without yield would need to know its size to build and return a full collection - then iterate over the required part of that collection?

Comment: Great example, I wanted to see how this was exactly done so I ran it through dotpeek and rewrote it into c# code the compiler generated code. You can view and run the code here to see the results. https://dotnetfiddle.net/8rjtBT

Comment: At last I got what `yield` is and where it can be used. Great explanation that shows that you can not do the same with returning a collection.

Comment: "There would be no way to return a list with infinite length and use the first 100 items."
Where is the Problem? I just take the first 100 items of the "infinite" list. I don't know what I would need yield for.

Answer (score 24):

The fine answers here suggest that a benefit of `yield return` is that ***you don't need to create a list***; Lists can be expensive.  (Also, after a while, you'll find them bulky and inelegant.)

But what if you don't have a List?

`yield return` allows you to traverse **data structures** (not necessarily Lists) in a number of ways.  For example, if your object is a Tree, you can traverse the nodes in pre- or post- order without creating other lists or changing the underlying data structure.

```
public IEnumerable<T> InOrder()
{
    foreach (T k in kids)
        foreach (T n in k.InOrder())
            yield return n;
    yield return (T) this;
}

public IEnumerable<T> PreOrder()
{
    yield return (T) this;
    foreach (T k in kids)
        foreach (T n in k.PreOrder())
            yield return n;
}
```

Comment: This example also highlights the case of delegation. If you have a collection that under certain circumstances could contain the items of other collections, it's very simple to iterate and use yield return instead of building a full list of all results and returning that.

Comment: Now C# just needs to implement `yield!` the way F# does so that you don't need all the `foreach` statements.

Comment: Incidentally, your example shows one of the "dangers" of `yield return`: it's often not obvious when it will yield efficient or inefficient code.  Although `yield return` can be used recursively, such usage will impose significant overhead on the processing of deeply-nested enumerators.  Manual state management may be more complicated to code, but run much more efficiently.

Answer (score 18):

### Lazy Evaluation/Deferred Execution

The "yield return" iterator blocks won't execute *any* of the code until you actually call for that specific result.  This means they can also be chained together efficiently.  Pop quiz: how many times will the following code iterate over the file?

```
var query = File.ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
                            .Where(l => l.Contains("search text") )
                            .Select(l => int.Parse(l.SubString(5,8))
                            .Where(i => i > 10 );

int sum=0;
foreach (int value in query) 
{
    sum += value;
}
```

The answer is exactly one, and that not until way down in the `foreach` loop. Even though I have three separate linq operator functions, we still only loop through the contents of the file one time.

This has benefits other than performance. For example, I can write a fair simple and *generic* method to read and pre-filter a log file once, and use that same method in several different places, where each use adds on different filters. Thus, I maintain good performance while also efficiently re-using code.

### Infinite Lists

See my answer to this question for a good example:
[C# fibonacci function returning errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076001/need-help-with-c-fibonacci)

Basically, I implement the fibonacci sequence using an iterator block that will never stop (at least, not before reaching MaxInt), and then use that implementation in a safe way.

### Improved Semantics and separation of concerns

Again using the file example from above, we can now easily separate the code that reads the file from the code that filters out un-needed lines from the code that actually parses the results.  That first one, especially, is very re-usable.

This is one of those things that's much harder to explain with prose than it is to just show a simple visual<sup>1</sup>:

[image: Imperative vs Functional Separation of Concerns]

If you can't see the image, it shows two versions of the same code, with background highlights for different concerns. The linq code has all of the colors nicely grouped, while the traditional imperative code has the colors intermingled. The author argues (and I concur) that this result is typical of using linq vs using imperative code... that linq does a better job organizing your code to have a better flow between sections.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I believe this to be the original source:  https://twitter.com/mariofusco/status/571999216039542784. Also note that this code is Java, but the C# would be similar.</sup>

Comment: Deferred execution is probably the biggest benefit of iterators.

Comment: I don't care about the colors. I like the imperative code more. This code style works everywhere and not just when I have linq.

Answer (score 12):

Sometimes the sequences you need to return are just too large to fit in the memory. For example, about 3 months ago I took part in a project for data migration between MS SLQ databases. Data was exported in XML format. **Yield return** turned out to be quite useful with **XmlReader**. It made programming quite easier. For example, suppose a file had 1000 **Customer** elements - if you just read this file into memory, this will require to store all of them in memory at the same time, even if they are handled sequentially. So, you can use iterators in order to traverse the collection one by one. In that case you have to spend just memory for one element.

As it turned out, using **XmlReader** for our project was the only way to make the application work - it worked for a long time, but at least it did not hang the entire system and did not raise **OutOfMemoryException**. Of course, you can work with **XmlReader** without yield iterators. But iterators made my life much easier (I would not write the code for import so quickly and without troubles). Watch this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387013.aspx) in order to see, how yield iterators are used for solving real problems (not just scientific with infinite sequences).

Answer (score 9):

In toy/demonstration scenarios, there isn't a lot of difference.  But there are situations where yielding iterators are useful - sometimes, the entire list isn't available (e.g. streams), or the list is computationally expensive and unlikely to be needed in its entirety.

Answer (score 2):

If the entire list is gigantic, it might eat a lot of memory just to sit around, whereas with the yield you only play with what you need, when you need it, regardless of how many items there are.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this discussion on Eric White's blog (excellent blog by the way) on [lazy versus eager evaluation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/Lazy-Evaluation-_2800_and-in-contrast_2C00_-Eager-Evaluation_2900_.aspx).

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Using the `yield return` you can iterate over items without ever having to build a list.  If you don't need the list, but want to iterate over some set of items it can be easier to write

```
foreach (var foo in GetSomeFoos()) {
    operate on foo
}
```

Than

```
foreach (var foo in AllFoos) {
    if (some case where we do want to operate on foo) {
        operate on foo
    } else if (another case) {
        operate on foo
    }
}
```

You can put all of the logic for determining whether or not you want to operate on foo inside your method using yield returns and you foreach loop can be much more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my previous accepted answer to exactly the same question:

[Yield keyword value added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384392/yield-keyword-value-added/384404#384404)

Another way to look at iterator methods is that they do the hard work of turning an algorithm "inside out". Consider a parser. It pulls text from a stream, looks for patterns in it and generates a high-level logical description of the content.

Now, I can make this easy for myself as a parser author by taking the SAX approach, in which I have a callback interface that I notify whenever I find the next piece of the pattern. So in the case of SAX, each time I find the start of an element, I call the `beginElement` method, and so on.

But this creates trouble for my users. They have to implement the handler interface and so they have to write a state machine class that responds to the callback methods. This is hard to get right, so the easiest thing to do is use a stock implementation that builds a DOM tree, and then they will have the convenience of being able to walk the tree. But then the whole structure gets buffered up in memory - not good.

But how about instead I write my parser as an iterator method?

```
IEnumerable<LanguageElement> Parse(Stream stream)
{
    // imperative code that pulls from the stream and occasionally 
    // does things like:

    yield return new BeginStatement("if");

    // and so on...
}
```

That will be no harder to write than the callback-interface approach - just yield return an object derived from my `LanguageElement` base class instead of calling a callback method.

The user can now use foreach to loop through my parser's output, so they get a very convenient imperative programming interface.

The result is that both sides of a custom API *look like they're in control*, and hence are easier to write and understand.

Answer (score 2):

The basic reason for using yield is it generates/returns a list by itself. We can use the returned list for iterating further.

Comment: Conceptually correct but technically incorrect. It returns an instance of IEnumerable which is simply abstracting an iterator. That iterator is actually logic to get the next item and not a materialized list. Using `return yield` doesn't generate a list, it only generates the next item in the list and only when asked for (iterated).