# Union of two results

Tags: c#, linq

```
Dictionary<int, int> first = new Dictionary<int, int>();
first.Add(1, 5);
first.Add(2, 4);
first.Add(3, 7);

Dictionary<int, int> second = new Dictionary<int, int>();
second .Add(2, 1);
second .Add(3, 2);
second .Add(4, 3);

var c = first.Where(x => x.Value > 5).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();  // this gives me 3
var d = second.Where(x => x.Value >= 2).Select(x => x.Key).ToList(); // this give me 3 and 4
```

I need to combine result of `c` and `d`, which should be `3` and `4`.

Can I do this union of these two result in a LINQ query?

Comment: Did you mean to add the last three entries to `second`?

Comment: sorry folks, fixed typos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use Enumerable's `Union` method as follows:

```
var union = c.Union(d);
```

MSDN on `Union` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Or, if doing this as a one-shot query:

```
var union = first.Where(x => x.Value > 5)
                 .Select(x => x.Key)
                 .Union(second.Where(y => y.Value >= 2)
                              .Select(y => y.Key))
                 .ToList();
```

This might actually be more preferable, too, since `Union` employs deferred execution.

Comment: @Asad, no, This will not work. Union will use the default equality comparer and in this case reference, You will end up with `3,3,4` items in the list.

Comment: @Habib Right again. I realized this a few minutes after I posted the comment. Need to think before I comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var combined = c.Union(d);
```

If you are only interested in `Union` then you can remove the call to `ToList` for `c` and `d` like, *(see [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898128/is-linq-lazy-evaluated))*:

```
var c = first.Where(x => x.Value > 5).Select(x => x.Key);  // this gives me 3
var d = second.Where(x => x.Value >= 2).Select(x => x.Key); // this give me 3 and 4

var combined = c.Union(d).ToList();
```

Comment: Not really sure what you meant, but here is what OP is asking  "I think need to combine result of c and d, which should be 3 and 4."