# yield return slow database calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, yield-return

In my ASP project there is code like this, to populate `rr` with `RegulationGroups`

```
private IEnumerable<RegulationGroup> LoadRegulations(string moduleName)  
{
    // database calls
    yield return subLrg;
}
```

In a separate class, the code loops over multiple times

```
foreach (RegulationGroup rg in rr.RegulationGroups)     
{

}
```

Each time the code loops over `RegulationGroups` the database call occurs. How can I avoid the database calls?

I think  I can

1. do away with `yield return` and use a `List`
2. cache the `IEnumerable` in a list and use it in my module so that it doesn't affect any other code using the `LoadRegulations` method.

Comment: Side note: your variable names are smwht shrtnd. Please consider using reasonably understandable names (or clearly fake) in public code.

Comment: You also most likely don't need to `yield return` the items.  Chances are `AsEnumerable` will work just as well, and be a fair bit more efficient at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid it by *materializing* the query, f.e. by using `ToList()`:

```
var regulations = LoadRegulations("moduleName").ToList();
```

It's due to the nature of `deferred execution`  of the `yield return`.

[What is the purpose/advantage of using yield return iterators in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088442/what-is-the-purpose-advantage-of-using-yield-return-iterators-in-c)

Comment: I don't see any mention of LINQ in the question. `yield return` also uses deferred execution, but saying it's caused by something in LINQ is inaccurate.

Comment: Yeah, except now the link doesn't make sense, because it talks about LINQ, not `yield return`. :-)