# using loop inside linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Very short brief overview on my business:
A customer needs our periodic service, so we have some reservedServices which reserved already with a specified duration. Everyday we should retrieve those reservedServices between `start` date and `end` date based on their turn.

For this purpose I need sth like this:

```
1 using (MehrpouyanEntities dbContext = new MehrpouyanEntities())
2 {        
3     var query1 = dbContext.ReservedServices.Where(r => 
4                  DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, r.Duration) >= start && 
5                  DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, r.Duration) <= end);
6     var query2 = dbContext.ReservedServices.Where(r => 
7                  DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, 2*r.Duration) >= start && 
8                  DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, 2*r.Duration) <= end);
9      .
10     .
11     .
12      var queryN = dbContext.ReservedServices.Where(r => 
13                 DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, N * r.Duration) >= start && 
14                 DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, N * r.Duration) <= end);
15     // this means that the loop continues untill:
       // DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, N * r.Duration) > end
16     return query1.Concat(query2). ... .Concat(queryN).ToList();
17 }
```

How can I implement the above code using a loop structure?

**Note1:** The `N` parameter is various for different `r`, I need to implement a loop inside query.

**Note2--over emphasizes Note1 :** `N` as the Upper-bound of the loop, acquire inside query based on each record `r` , so each record `r` may has different `N`. More precisely the loop continues until `DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, N * r.Duration) > end`

**Note3--example:**

```
Customer A: LastServiceDate = october 05 2017
            Duration = 7 (Weekly)
start = october 06 2017
end = october 27 2017
```

I want to retrieve 3 services as follows:

1. october 12 2017
2. october 19 2017
3. october 26 2017

Comment: Not seeing a question here? Are you having difficulties? Is something not working?

Comment: The `N` is various for different `r`, I need to implement a loop inside query. Note my comment: this means that the loop continues untill DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, r.Duration) > end

Comment: You probably want a cross join for a Cartesian product.

Comment: dear @Kyle not actually, your comment is the side effect of my issue, the main problem is integration all query in one linq using a for loop. If we have one query, therefore we would not need Concatenation any more.

Comment: Could you elaborate what `N` is, and how to you acquire if? for example, will you have an array of numbers `int[] NArray = { 1 , 2 , 3 ... }`? if so, how would this array be populated, and will you know how many elements in it?

Comment: Salam Dear @FarzanMirheydari , `N` as the Upper-bound of loop, acquire inside query based on each record `r`. Note the comment please: //this means that the loop continues untill DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, r.Duration) > end

Comment: Do you really need the records to be duplicated by the count of matches in the result set?

Comment: Or just the list of services which has to be processed between `start` and `end`?

Comment: Dear @IvanStoev please have a sight at my question, I have provided an example.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky question. And of course cannot be solved with LINQ to Entities query. But can be solved by mixed LINQ to Entities/LINQ to Objects approach.

Let split the problem in two parts.

(1) Retrieve all service records having

```
LastServiceDate + i * Duration >= start &&
LastServiceDate + i * Duration <= end
```

for any integer `i`, where `+` means add days.

Let take the first condition

```
LastServiceDate + i * Duration >= start
```

Therefore it's satisfied for any

```
i >= (start - LastServiceDate) / Duration
```

hence the first service date is (taking into account integer arithmetic)

```
LastServiceDate + Duration * ceiling((start - LastServiceDate) / Duration)
```

(2) For each service retrieved by the first step, generate all service dates between `start` and `end` and produce the final result.

(1) can be implemented with LINQ to Entities (database) query, while (2) will be done in memory using LINQ to Objects.

Here is the implementation of the above concept:

```
var dbQuery = 
    from r in dbContext.ReservedServices
    where r.LastServiceDate <= start
    let firstDate = DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(r.LastServiceDate, start).Value + r.Duration - 1) / r.Duration) * r.Duration).Value
    where firstDate <= end
    select r;

var result = (
    from r in dbQuery.AsEnumerable()
    let firstDate = r.LastServiceDate.AddDays((((start - r.LastServiceDate).Days + r.Duration - 1) / r.Duration) * r.Duration)
    let count = 1 + (end - firstDate).Days / r.Duration
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    select new { Service = r, Date = firstDate.AddDays(i * r.Duration) }
    ).ToList();
```

You can adjust the final anonymous type projection to anything which meets your requirements.

Comment: Boy, I nearly hit the final close vote half an hour ago but waited because I saw your comments. Glad you could make sense of it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<ReservedService> myReservedServices;
var runningQuery = new List<ReservedService>();

var index = 1;
do{
    // query here, you need to set myReservedServices to a value
    // and check if it's non-empty to decide if you'd like to check the next day
    runningQuery.Add(query);

    // increment the index
    index++;
} while(myReservedServices != null && myReservedServices.Any());
```

Comment: You might want to materialize `myReservedServices`, so you don't query it twice (adding + not-empty checking)

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over your `query` till your query returns nothing

```
IEnumerable<Data> GetData() {
    using (MehrpouyanEntities dbContext = new MehrpouyanEntities()) {
        bool hasData = true;
        for (int i = 1; hasData; ++i) {
            int n = i;
            hasData = false;
            var query = dbContext.ReservedServices.Where(r =>
                            DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, n * r.Duration) >= start &&
                            DbFunctions.AddDays(r.LastServiceDate, n * r.Duration) <= end);

            foreach (var item in query) {
                hasData = true;
                yield return item;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: how about `if(query.Any()) { hasData = true; queryList.Add(query); } ` instead of the `foreach` ?

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari That would cause the same query to be run twice since it is not materialized.

Comment: @FarzanMirheydari I don't see any benefits to doing it that way, especially when the function returns an `IEnumerable`. I wish C# team introduces a variant of the `yield return` keyword to return the flattened `IEnumerable`. Then we could write it as `yield return many query`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 @Vikhram thank you both, wasn't aware of that. A followup question would be, would using `ToList()` like `queryList.Add(query.toList())` help with the materialization problem ?

Comment: The `.ToList()` needs to happen anything that causes the `IQueryable` to materialize which in this case is the `.AddRange` and `Any`. Here is what you want to do: `var materialized = query.ToList(); if (materialized.Any()) { /*...*/ results.AddRange(materialized); }`

Comment: @Xiaoy312 @FarzanMirheydari The beauty of `IEnumerable<T>` returning functions (like LINQ functions and my function)  is that they can be lazily evaluated. That means, not only does it not take extra space to store the  whole list but also it doesn't need any extra processing till it is traversed by the caller. It is typically a good practice to procrastinate in code evaluation :). You should read up on [What is the purpose/advantage of using yield return iterators in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088442/what-is-the-purpose-advantage-of-using-yield-return-iterators-in-c)